How can I get a navigatorkey in Flutter App? not null
When I click on the notification on background, it doesn't redirect to the page I want.
I checked, and navigatorkey.currentContext is null.
(I'm using go_router, get_it, provider)
I referred to the blog below.
https://zzingonglog.tistory.com/40
https://zzingonglog.tistory.com/41
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  String payloadData = jsonEncode(message.data);
  print('Got a message in background');
  if (message.notification != null) {
    PushNotification.showSimpleNotification(
      title: message.notification!.title!,
      body: message.notification!.body!,
      payload: payloadData,
    );
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await PushNotification.init();
  await PushNotification.localNotiInit();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    String payloadData = jsonEncode(message.data);
    print('Got a message in foreground');
    if (message.notification != null) {
      PushNotification.showSimpleNotification(
        title: message.notification!.title!,
        body: message.notification!.body!,
        payload: payloadData,
      );
    }
  });

  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
    String payload =
        notificationAppLaunchDetails!.notificationResponse?.payload ?? "";
    print('Got a message in terminated');
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      navigatorKey.currentContext
          ?.push('/notification/message', extra: payload);
    });
  }
  diSetup();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          // backgroundColor: ColorStyles.primary40,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyles.extraLargeTextBold.copyWith(
            color: ColorStyles.black,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried defining Globalkey here and there.

The reason it isn't navigating to the correct screen/page once clicking a notification, Is, since you have to actually assign the key to the MaterialApp.
Essentially, you need to 'tie' the key to the MaterialApp to let it know what key to use.
In your code:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // --> Add this line

